# AsEnumerable with stored procedure using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, asenumerable

I am new in using stored procedure using Microsoft Entity Framework. To do some practice I used Northwind database and I was successfully able to do something like this:

```
var qry = (from row in dbContext.CustOrderHist("custID").AsEnumerable()
    select row).Skip(10).Take(10);
```

Then I have my own DB I am working with it also has a few stored procedures and I similarly used the 'Add Function Import; feature of .Net to create ComplexType to get the stored procedure results (the way I practiced in Northwind Model).

But when I try to do the same:

```
var qry = (from row in _dbContext.spComplianceReport("SomeID", null).AsEnumerable()
    select row).Skip(10).Take(10);
```

It would not work, and gives error about AsEnumerable(). The following error:

> System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult
>   does not contain a definition for AsEnumerable and no extension method
>   AsEnumerable accepting a first argument of type
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

This problem is with my every stored procedure in my Model. What can be different with my Model than the Northwind.

Comment: Does `spComplianceReport` return a table at all?

Comment: It returns the rows with 5 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok doing the following resolved my problem:

```
using System.Linq;
```